# Create circle around user inputted point and plot on map with custom latlon points

Tags: tableau-api

I have a question about if something is possible using Tableau.

I already have a coastline plotted on one map using custom LatLon coordinates and I would like to take a user inputted Lat and Lon and plot a circle around it with let's say radius 10 and display it on the same map.

I was using this tutorial before to plot a circle: 
https://www.crowdanalytix.com/communityBlog/customers-within-n-miles-radius-analysis-using-tableau

But I don't think the same approach can work with user-inputted fields because then it would require restructuring the data..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a (much smarter LOL) coworker helped me figure this out.... 
So my goal was to graph distance band (like a distance of 5 miles around a coast) . In order to do this we can use the distance between two coastline points since they are connected by a line, not a curve...From there we can find the perpendicular point a certain distance away and connect those points. Much easier than my circle idea...